# How to do an outer join in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have defined two entities that map to two tables in my database. In SQL I would do a join like this:

```
select *
from tableA a
left outer join tableB b on b.ID = a.ID
where some condition
```

How might I do this with a LINQ query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) on MSDN.

For example:

```
var query = from person in people
    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

Comment: I think it's this one : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx (Left outer join)

Comment: How would you accomplish this with the chain method syntax in LINQ?

Comment: You need to use the GroupJoin() method

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Using Labda Expressions you use a [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx)

Example:

```
var query =
  People
  .GroupJoin(
    Pets,
    person => person.PersonId,
    pet => per.Owner,
    (person, petCollection) =>
       new
       {
          Person = person,
          Pets = petCollection.Select(pet => pet.Name),
       });
```